# Multivariate statistical analysis using R.. How to see significant difference when rows and columns both are groups (Categories-Ordered)

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, bioinformatics, statistical-test

My Data looks like following Where DFD is my data frame.

```
DFD
  Names  BP  jobcode bp_Category
1     A 100   Doctor      low_BP
2     B 150   Doctor   Medium_BP
3     C 200 Engineer     High_BP
4     D 110 Engineer      low_BP
5     E 160  Student   Medium_BP
```

Here is how i get percentage of each jobcodes suffering from Low,high and Medium BP as follows.

> 

```
tabLE<-table(DFD$bp_Category,DFD$jobcode)
> prop.table(tabLE,2)*100

            Doctor Engineer Student
  low_BP        50       50       0
  Medium_BP     50        0     100
  High_BP        0       50       0
```

I want to ask how and by which statistical test i can see the significant difference among three job codes respectively for all three bp_categories. For example i want to see if the Engineers have significantly highest percentage of Medium_BP among Doctor and Student or not??

```
Data 

Names<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
BP<-c(100,150,200,110,160)
jobcode<-c("Doctor","Doctor","Engineer","Engineer","Student")
jobcode<-ordered(jobcode)
DFD<-data.frame(Names,BP,jobcode)
DFD$bp_Category[DFD$BP<140]<-"low_BP"
DFD$bp_Category[DFD$BP<170 & DFD$BP>140]<-"Medium_BP"
DFD$bp_Category[DFD$BP<201 & DFD$BP>170]<-"High_BP"
DFD$bp_Category<-ordered(DFD$bp_Category, levels = c("low_BP","Medium_BP","High_BP"))
tabDFD <- with(DFD, table(DFD$bp_Category,DFD$jobcode))
tabLE<-table(DFD$bp_Category,DFD$jobcode)
prop.table(tabLE,2)*100
```

Comment: how many observations do you really have? If you have only 5, it doesn't make sense to test. If it's more than that, you can do a chi square test

Comment: I have around 10000 observations.

Comment: the example is reproducable, i will appreciate if you explain me output after running test.

Comment: as in, are you only interested in "Engineers have significantly highest percentage of Medium_BP among Doctor and Student or not", or you are interested in all possible comparisons

Comment: I am interested in all possible comparisons.

Comment: I want to test if there any difference of Medium BP among Engineer, Doctor and Students. same is for Low_BP and High_BP. Precisely i am looking for three p-values. One p.value for High_BP, one for low_bp and one for medium_BP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simulated dataset, where the proportions are more or less equal among BP and occupations:

```
set.seed(111)
DFD = data.frame(jobcode = sample(c("Doctor","Engineer","Student"),10000,replace=TRUE),
bp_Category = sample(c("low_BP","Medium_BP","High_BP"),10000,replace=TRUE)
)
```

Since this is simulated under the null, you see it's approximately 33% for all:

```
tabDFD <- with(DFD, table(DFD$bp_Category,DFD$jobcode))
tabLE<-table(DFD$bp_Category,DFD$jobcode)
prop.table(tabLE,2)*100

              Doctor Engineer  Student
  High_BP   32.81156 33.89058 32.96930
  low_BP    33.68453 32.73556 33.82527
  Medium_BP 33.50391 33.37386 33.20543
```

We can do a chi-square test for each row, but we need to know the expected proportions of Doctor, Engineer, Student, so we get this:

```
probs = colSums(tabLE)/sum(tabLE)
```

And then for each row, we test how much each cell deviates from what we expect:

```
library(broom)
library(purrr)

results = split(as.matrix(tabLE),rownames(tabLE)) %>% 
map_dfr(~tidy(chisq.test(.x,p=probs)),.id="BP") 

 results
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  BP        statistic p.value parameter method                                  
  <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                   
1 High_BP      0.676    0.713         2 Chi-squared test for given probabilities
2 low_BP       0.697    0.706         2 Chi-squared test for given probabilities
3 Medium_BP    0.0451   0.978         2 Chi-squared test for given probabilities
```